# Generic function with dynamic return types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Admittedly I am fairly new to TypeScript and I am trying to figure out how to create a generic shared library function `getFlags` that takes an array of string identifiers and returns an object whose keys are the identifiers and whose properties are the flag objects. The flag objects, all have a similar shape except for their `config` property ... which will have its own unique shape.

For example:

```
const flags = getFlags(['flagA', 'flagB'])
```

The resulting `flags` would look something like this

```
{
  flagA: {
   name: 'a',
   value: 'test1',
   config: {
     foo: 'red'
   }
  },
  flagB: {
   name: 'b',
   value: 'test2',
   config: {
     bar: 123
   }
  },
  // ....
}
```

My initial attempt at defining the types for this looks something like this:

```
type Flag<T> {
  name: string,
  value: string,
  config: T
}

type FlagList = {
  [key: string]: Flag<unknown>
}

type ConfigA {
  foo: string
}

type ConfigB {
  bar: number
}
```

What I want is a way to create a generic version of `getFlags` so that Typescript knows the type of the underlying config property for each of the flags returned.

```
const {flagA, flagB} = getFlags(['flagA','flagB'])

flagA.config.foo // OK
flagA.config.bar // Invalid
flagB.config.bar // OK
flagB.config.foo // Invalid

const {flagA, flagB, flagC, flagD} = getFlags(['flagA','flagB' 'flagC', 'flagD'])
```

The `getFlags` function would look something like this:

```
function getFlags(ids: string[]): FlagList {
  return retrieveFlagsByIds(ids)
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to tell TypeScript the type information for the config property.  One thought would be to pass the type somehow like this.  However there could be any number of these flags and that seems a bit crazy:

```
const { flagA, flagB } = getFlags<ConfigA, ConfigB>(['flagA','flagB'])

const { flagA, flagB, flagC, flagD, flagE } = getFlags<ConfigA, ConfigB, ConfigC, ConfigD, ConfigE>(['flagA','flagB', 'flagC', 'flagD', 'flagE'])
```

Because `getFlags` is a shared library function it isn't possible to know all the flag config types that a consumer may have.   Any ideas?

Comment: Wait, is it `getFlags(['flagA', 'flagB'])` or `getFlags(['a', 'b'])`?  Given that one of them seems to be an object *key* and the other seems to be the *value* of a property whose key is `name`, I'm confused about your actual intent here.  Could you make sure that you're being consistent in your examples and spell out the relationship you are envisioning?

Comment: Fixed ... thanks for the feedback.  Sorry about the inconsistency.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be inclined to make a helper object type `FlagConfigs` representing the mapping between the flag names and the config types:

```
interface FlagConfigs {
  flagA: { foo: string };
  flagB: { bar: number };
  flagC: { baz: boolean }
}
```

Then the call signature for `getFlags()` would look like this:

```
declare function getFlags<K extends keyof FlagConfigs>(flags: K[]): { 
  [P in K]: Flag<FlagConfigs[P]> 
};
```

Here we're making the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in `K`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of the keys of `FlagConfigs`.  This union will look like `"flagA" | "flagB"` etc, so it will have a member for each distinct value in the `flags` array, and that's what takes care of the problem you're having with a possibly unbounded number of type parameters.  The single `K` type parameter can represent all of them.  For the return type, we transform `K` by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) each flag type in it, `P`, to a property where `P` is the key and where `Flag<FlagConfigs[P]>` is the value type.  This latter type means "look up the `P` key in `FlagConfigs`, take that property, and use it as the `config` property type in a `Flag`.

Let's see if it works:

```
const {flagA, flagB} = getFlags(['flagA','flagB'])
flagA.config.foo // okay
flagA.config.bar // error!
flagB.config.bar // okay
flagB.config.foo // error!
```

Looks good.

As for the *implementation* of `getFlags()`, that's up to you.  You will likely need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that your implementation will actually conform to the call signature.  It is unlikely to be able to verify this on its own.  So be careful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIBs4HMDCB7EGYLAZ2QG8AoZZGTLAQQC4La88WSwpQtkBfANzVa9AEItyyAEZwoLEAFcAttOgDhNOthySZcAF4tp7dBDggBlfpUpgAngAcUGbAB4AKgD5kAXgoiIHDKEJzcvAA0IgBucOiKochcPCBYUTQIBERYLB7WtgAmEAiYUCgwiiAIYMAEyFgQYK6kbgDSyBAAHpAgBWQA1hD2eDBo9PiExCReABTapCytANoAugCUeksACsigyK0rLM1uzRPZJNsrPkK2mSBcFPMMEaLYYvx+9Y3NJDNLAORPf4RQHif7rShPAB0d2yUJg7GQAHokcg8P04PZIfQGDCssQobIoMjUdAoHgoABCbFvPGTLCEuQktEYrHzMR0uEIvDMskU6lAA)

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for the response.  

Another important clarification I should make is that `getFlags` is a shared library function and wont really know about shape of all the flag types.   The consumer of the library function will however know.

Comment: Hmm, then I'm not sure enough about how this is going to work.  Possibly the library containing `getFlags()` could expose a `FlagConfigs` interface with nothing in it, and then library consumers can [augment the interface via declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to add the flags they know about.  Like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-s5vvd).  Does that work for you?